# Swing: Delegate events to child components of transformed parent

Tags: java, swing, events, transformation, delegation

I've got a custom component `GameViewCanvas extends JPanel` that will hold a number of tiles (800x800 textures). Now in GameViewCanvas I've overridden the `paint()` method, so that it will paint the children on a transformed canvas (zoom, panning and rotation).

I now want to delegate events like MouseEvent and MouseMotionEvent to the respective children - the problem of course being that Swing has no idea where the children are on the actual frame. I thought I might be able to just override a method like `getComponentAt` in the parent but no such luck - I figure Swing is looping through the children directly?

Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, so please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question, 1+. I don't know the solution, but if this were my problem, I'd search through the Swing source code to see if this could give me a clue.

Comment: Google `JXLayer` (AKA `JLayer` in Java 7).  This does exactly what you just asked.  Because they've disappeared from the Net, I've made available all of the examples [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1hmvypp19oqy1/JXLayer-PBJar-Demo.zip)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `JXLayer`.  It does exactly what you've just asked.

There are some excellent examples by Piet Blok, which have, unfortunately, disappeared off the net.  To this end, I've made them available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1hmvypp19oqy1/JXLayer-PBJar-Demo.zip).

Take a look at the `TestWrapped` demo in the pbjar source.  It is probably the (among) the best example.

[image]

ps - `JXLayer` is now officially part of Java 7, known as `JLayer`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to solve the delegation problem. However, since I now do the transforming in the LayerUI, the canvas is clipped according to the bounds of the JLayer component so that when I zoom out, only part of the available space is actually painted.