# Set resolution of a specific JFrame, not the computer's resolution

Tags: java, swing, size, jframe, resolution

Is there anyway in Java to set the resolution of a specific JFrame rather than changing the computer's resolution, meaning that if I have JFrame with a size of 100x100 can I make it so the top left point will be (0,0) and the bottom right will be (50,50)?  These points being the coordinates inside the JFrame, for example when using Graphics (java.awt.Graphics).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Graphics2D` has a scale option, look after it in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html).

In your case, it's simply this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.scale(0.5, 0.5); // 50% x and 50% y

    // rest of rendering
}
```

Comment: Not until you call `super.paintComponent` ;).  Scaling will also NOT effect events (such as mouse events)

Comment: Anyway to do this AND effect events?

Comment: Look up JXLayer (or JLayer under windows)

Comment: multiply the event's coordinates, the same way as in the scale, `x = evt.getX()*0.5` etc.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623276/swing-delegate-events-to-child-components-of-transformed-parent/16623435#16623435) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324460/rotating-a-jtextfield-vertically/14328881#14328881) for examples